# Hide specific elements with data-testid

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table with columns that shows daily and weekly prices, but I want to hide the daily price. Can i somehow address the `data-testid` to hide the element?

```
<td class="rate-price" data-testid="rates.rate-0.price-daily"><p class="heavy rate-price-column">Pro Tag</p>€  786</td>
```

I then would need to hide the header of the column as well, but it doesn't have a specific ID. It's the first line here:

```
<th class="col-header">Pro Tag</th>
<th class="col-header">Wochenpreis</th>
```

any ideas?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Add a `display: none` to the element?

Comment: You need to add enough of your “*[mcve]*” code to allow us to reproduce your problem, without needing to make guesses about your structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide this element with the following code:

```
$("[data-testid='rates.rate-0.price-daily']").hide()
```

Comment: This will mess with the layout as your hiding a `td` inside a table though - [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xr3sy6wk/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to hide td elements having data-testid that ends with .price-daily?

```
$("td[data-testid$='price-daily']").css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: This will mess with the layout as your hiding a `td` inside a table though - [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xr3sy6wk/)

Comment: yes unfortunately there are not enough information to do better. The table should be supposed to have that field repeated for each rows so it shouldn't mess up with the layout as long as you take care of hiding the header column as well.

Comment: Correct, just wanted to point that out. Possibly you could replace the `td` with an empty one though

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, the table layout and cell styles are not affected.

In `Option 2` Wrap is required because the plain text `€ 786` cannot be hidden if it does not have a parent.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Option 1: Remove content
  //$('td[data-testid="rates.rate-0.price-daily"]').html('');
  
  // Option 2: Hide content
  let $div = $('div').css('display', 'none');
  $('td[data-testid="rates.rate-0.price-daily"]').wrapInner($div);

});
```

```css
table, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> other column </td>
      <td class="rate-price" data-testid="rates.rate-0.price-daily">
        <p class="heavy rate-price-column">Pro Tag</p>€ 786
      </td>
      <td> other column </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> other column </td>
      <td class="rate-price">
        <p class="heavy rate-price-column">Pro Tag without data-testid: </p>€ 555</td>
      <td> other column </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```